# lowdb não tá atualizando pro resto do código (só pra uma parte dele)

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, chatbot, discord

Então, eu tô tentando programar um bot pro discord (por favor não me julguem)
Eu queria fazer com que uma mensagem fosse salva num banco de dados lowdb e depois, enviada sempre após 10 outras mensagens no chat em questão.

Ou seja, usando como exemplo a mensagem "hello world". Um comando é dado pra guardar essa mensagem "hello world" e a cada 10 mensagens no chat em que esse comando foi dado, o bot enviaria a mensagem "hello world"

Daí, eu tentei usar 3 arquivos pra isso:
1 - O index do bot
2 - O arquivo contendo o código do comando (dentro de uma pasta "comandos")
3 - O banco de dados lowdb

No banco de dados lowdb, existem as seguintes informações:
"contador": 0 // conta quantas mensagens foram enviadas
"status": false // false significa que a contagem de mensagens não deve ser feita. se for true, a contagem de mensagens pode rolar normalmente
"trigger": 10 // assim que a contagem de mensagens for igual a esse valor, a mensagem guardada (hello world) é enviada

O arquivo 1 (index) seria o que enviaria a mensagem:
Ele usa o evento "raw" pra detectar mensagens enviadas e, pra cada mensagem enviada, ele adiciona +1 no valor "contador" dentro do banco. Quando esse valor do "contador" chegar à quantidade igual ao valor do "trigger", ele envia uma mensagem (já guardada no banco) e muda o valor do "contador" pra 0 novamente.

O arquivo 2 (comando) faz três coisas:
A primeira é guardar a mensagem que vai ser enviada. A segunda é alternar o valor "status" entre true e false no banquinho. A terceira é alterar o valor "trigger" por um escolhido pelo usuário.

O arquivo 3 é o banco de dados lowdb:
Em que as configurações seriam salvas e verificadas.

**O problema:**
Tudo o que eu escrevi acima funciona quase perfeitamente. O problema é que o arquivo 1 (index) parece não considerar as edições feitas pelo arquivo 2 (comando)

Ou seja, quando o comando pra mudar o valor "status", de true pra false, é enviado, o arquivo 2 (comando) muda o valor pra false, mas o arquivo 1 (index) continua registrando as mensagens enviadas como se o valor não tivesse sido mudado.
Significa que O QUE DEVIA DESATIVAR ESSA FUNCIONALIDADE, NÃO FUNCIONA AAAAAAAAAAAA

Isso é porque o lowdb só atualiza as modificações feitas nele pra 1 único arquivo? ou alguma coisa assim? ou isso tem a ver com async funcitions?

Segue os pedaços relevantes do código

Arquivo 1 (index)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

const low = require('lowdb');
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync');
const adapter = new FileSync('bancoTest.json');
const db = low(adapter); 

[...]

client.on("message", async message => {
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
  const comando = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  try {
        let arquivoComando = require(`./comandos/${comando}.js`);
        arquivoComando.run(client, message, args, comando)
        } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})

client.on("raw", async data => {
    let valor = db.get('ListEnt').find({id:17}).value()
    try {
        if(data.t !== "MESSAGE_CREATE") return
        if(data.d.guild_id !== valor.guild) return   
        if(data.d.channel_id !== valor.channel) return
    } catch (error) {
        return
    }
    
    if(valor.status === true){
        db.get('ListEnt').find({id: 17}).assign({"contador": valor.contador+1}).write()
    }
    if(valor.contador === valor.trigger){
        db.get('ListEnt').find({id: 17}).assign({"contador": 0}).write()
        client.channels.cache.get(valor.channel).send(db.get('ListEnt').find({id: 16}).value())
    }
})
```

Arquivo 2 (comando):

```
exports.run = (client, message, args, comando) => {
       const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js'); 
       const low = require('lowdb');
       const coisa = require('../config.json')
       const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync');
       const adapter = new FileSync('bancoTest.json');
       const db = low(adapter);

   if(subCmd === "loop"){
        db.get('ListEnt').find({id: 17}).assign({"channel": message.channel.id}).write()
        db.get('ListEnt').find({id: 17}).assign({"guild": message.guild.id}).write()

        if(args[1]){
            if(isNaN(args[1])) return
            db.get('ListEnt').find({id: 17}).assign({"trigger": 
parseInt(args[1])}).write()
            return message.react('')
        }

        if(valor.status === false) {
            db.get('ListEnt').find({id: 17}).assign({"status": true}).write()
            return message.react("")
        } else if(valor.status === true) {
            db.get('ListEnt').find({id: 17}).assign({"status": false}).write()
            return message.react("⏹️")
    }

}
```

Arquivo 3 (banco):

```
   {
      "id": 16,
      "content": "",
      "embed": {
        "title": "Lista de Prováveis Mortos (0)",
        "type": "rich",
        "description": "\n          \n          \n          \n          \n          \n          \n          \n          \n          \n          \n          \n          \n          \n          \n          \n    ",
        "url": null,
        "timestamp": null,
        "color": 3514093,
        "fields": [],
        "thumbnail": null,
        "image": null,
        "author": null,
        "footer": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "channel": "1026355890309308446",
      "guild": "790241446992019467",
      "contador": 8,
      "status": true,
      "trigger": 10
    }
```

Eu tenho fortes suspeitas de que o problema tenha alguma coisa a ver com sincronização, mas num manjo o suficiente pra resolver :(

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAhP4.png)

Answer (score 0):

[resposta:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kppeZ.png)

Para resolver o problema descrito na pergunta, uma coisa que você pode fazer é garantir que o arquivo JSON esteja sendo escrito de volta ao disco a cada vez que você faz uma atualização nele. Isso pode ser feito adicionando a seguinte linha ao final de cada operação de atualização:

lua
Copy code
db.write();
Isso fará com que as alterações feitas na memória sejam imediatamente escritas no arquivo JSON no disco, tornando-as visíveis a qualquer outro processo que esteja lendo o arquivo.

Além disso, verifique se você está abrindo o arquivo apenas uma vez e o está mantendo aberto durante todo o tempo em que sua aplicação estiver em execução. Se você estiver abrindo o arquivo várias vezes ao longo da execução da sua aplicação, as alterações feitas em uma instância não serão visíveis em outra instância, o que pode levar a problemas semelhantes aos descritos na pergunta.

Espero que isso ajude a resolver o seu problema!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).